# Preview on Catalina 10.15.7 cannot open PS files

Tags: catalina, preview, postscript

Does anyone know of any setting that prevents `Preview` from even trying to open PS files on Catalina?

The PS files are not corrupted, if I convert them to PDF with `ps2pdf` they open just fine, even in `Preview`

[image: open file dialog]

Comment: "even trying to open" - how are you trying to open them & what error do you get?

Comment: Please have a look at the screenshot - it shows the ps files grayed out, so the `File->Open` from `Preview` can't even select those files.